# Example of infinitely differentiable function such that $f^{(k)}(0) = a_k$

Tags: derivatives

I want to find an infinitely differentiable function such that $f^{(k)}(0) = a_k$, where $a_k$ is some sequence of real numbers. My attempt was to raise $e$ to some power, but I have not gotten far. I feel like there should be a pretty simple simple solution, but for some reason I can't find it.

Comment: Just control the $C^k$ norm at each stage iteratively by controlling the interval and the bump function decay rates.